# multiple docker containers not exposed using port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have created a `docker-compose.yml` that brings up 2 linked container, when using the same file in another directory using `docker-compose up` command   considering the changing exposed port, it brings up the first container, but other container is not accessible even they are showing up and running when running `docker -ps`

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  web:
    image: myodoo8
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - o1-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - ./o1-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - ./backups:/var/backups


volumes:
  o1-web-data:
  o1-db-data:
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your `docker-compose.yml` file, along with perhaps a clear example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: What happens when you try `docker ps -a`?

Comment: All the containers are up and running normally even those which are not accessible

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it have this?-

```
ports:
      - "8069:8069"
```